# Entity Framework code-first migrations does not generate a foreign key and ignores the ForeignKey data annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to add a foreign key to my database table using EF code-first migrations, but when I run `add-migration`, the `Up()` and `Down()` methods in the generated migration are empty.

The base table to which the foreign key should link is `Reservation` and the table to which I am trying to add the key is `Batch`.

**Reservation** model class:

```
public class Reservation
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservationId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    
    ...
}
```

**Batch** model class:

```
public class Batch
{
   [Key]
   public int BatchId { get; set; }
   
   public int ReservationId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ReservationId")]
   public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

The `Reservation` attribute was previously called `TempReservation` and did not have a `[ForeignKey]` annotation which is why the foreign key did not get created in the first place.

I tried fixing it by adding the `[ForeignKey]` annotation and changing the property name to `Reservation` like in the above code snippet shows, but to no avail.

The migration always ignores my changes, giving me empty `Up()` and `Down()`.

I have other model classes that follow the same "structure" and they all have foreign keys without any issues. The only difference is that I am adding this FK after the `Batch` table was already created.

Comment: The code you show doesn't indicate anything that could be wrong.

Comment: UPDATE: I am still not able to get it to generate the migration as it should, who knows why, but I was able to add the Foreign Key by adding `AddForeignKey("dbo.Batches", "ReservationId", "dbo.Reservations", "ReservationId", cascadeDelete: true);` manually to the migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you started from scratch, your code model setup should work, so your model looks ok. The problem is that by not using the `[ForeignKey]` attribute the first time, your database schema now likely has an additional [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) column called `Reservation_ReservationId`. However as this field isn't an active declaration in your model, it's hard to target directly as your convention configuration can greatly affect this, for instance, if you have configured the appropriate convention, the shadow property
may have already been named `ReservationId`.

> tried fixing it by adding the [ForeignKey] annotation and changing the property name to Reservation like in the above code snippet shows, but to no avail.

As suggested above, the database may have already generated the correct foreign keys in the database, based on `public virtual ICollection<Batch> Batches { get; set; }`.

Something to remember:

- Whenever making changes to the model that rename fields and or modify indexes or relationships on existing fields, you must perform these operations in *separate* migrations or the migration generation logic can't understand you will have to apply the change manually.

  - If you do these in one hit, you will almost always have to manually edit the migration file in some way.
- *after applying* your manually modified migration logic to the database, if you now run the `add-migration` command it should generate an empty migration. If this is the case then you can generally move on.

Instead you could have followed this process:

1. Rename the navigation property, and any other fields.
2. `Add-Migration`... review the generated output
3. 'Update-Database`...
4. Add the `ForeignKey` attribute
5. `Add-Migration`... review the output, if this is empty, check that the foreign key is not already correctly defined in the database
6. 'Update-Database`... if necessary

### Code First Migrations is not perfect out of the box

it is still a very usable tool but you need to review the generated code and add to is as necessary. It is not hard to extend it to support default value declarations, or any SQL DDL management queries when or if you need to.